# How to get nested values from Json and show in textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have the following JSON below:

```
{
  "Name": "Program",
  "Version": "5.5,
  "Packages": 
  {
    "Package": 
     [
      {
        "Pack": "Application1",
        "PackName": "Application1.zip",
      },
      {
        "Pack": "Application2",
        "PackName": "Application2.zip",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I know how to get the values of `Name` and `Versions` with this code:

```
string source = Jsontextbox.Text;
dynamic Name = JObject.Parse(source);
dynamic Version = JObject.Parse(source);
textbox1.Text = (Name.Name + Version.Version);
```

But I would like to know how to do that for the packages values.

I would like the **output** to be the following in a textbox:

```
Pack: Applcation1 
PackName: Application1.zip

Pack: Applcation2 
PackName: Application2.zip
```

I would prefer to use JSON.Net, but im fine with other options.

**EDIT: What im trying:**

```
public class Packages
    {
        public Package[] Package { get; set; }
    }
public class Package
    {
        public string Pack { get; set; }
        public string PackageName { get; set; }

    }
string source = textBox1.Text;
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Package>(source);
textBox6.Text = result.Pack;
```

But it's not working for some reason

Comment: Based on the JSON you provided, what should be the output?

Comment: Edited. Does that help?

Comment: You have invalid commas and a missing double quote in that JSON. Note that, after you have fixed it, you can generate the corresponding classes in Visual Studio using the `Edit => Paste Special => Paste JSON as classes` tool. Then, desrialize with `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(source);`

Comment: You should of course rename `RootObject` to something more related to your current objects *destination*.

Comment: It still doesn't work though when I rename it though. Since I have multiple sets of data for packages.

Comment: 1) Have you fixed the JSON? 2) You are missing the RootObject here. It's the class where you have `string Name`, `string Version` and `Packages Packages`. You need to pass this class to the deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

By Using NestedList

```
    class A{
    string Name{set;get};
string Version{set;get};
List<B>nestedList{set;get};
    }

class B{
string Pack{set;get};
string PackName{set;get};
}
```

it gives you strongly typed objects

A objA=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(your object)
[more infomration](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/1074904/how-to-convert-json-string-to-list-of-objects)

Comment: Could you give me an example of using the object desirlizer? For some reason I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(source);
JObject packages = JObject.Parse(json["Packages"].ToString());
JArray packageArray = (JArray)packages["Package"];

for (var i = 0; i < packageArray.Count; i++) {
    var pack = JObject.Parse(packageArray[i].ToString())["Pack"];
    var packName = JObject.Parse(packageArray[i].ToString())["PackName"];

    Console.WriteLine(pack);
    Console.WriteLine(packName);
}
```